# Dlookups with two or more criteria in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've searched around for a solution to this but am probably not asking the question correctly. I'm fairly new to Access but I need someone's help.

On my "CSEIrrelevants" form I have a couple of Dlookups to autupopulate after updating a previous field entry. They are CustomerName and AgreementName. Essentially, when someone enters a value into the CustomerID and AgreementID fields the subsequent two fields return values from CustomerDatabase Table from CustomerName and AgreementName columns.

The CustomerID Dlookup is working fine asthe references are unique but my problem arises when dealing with the Agreement IDs as these are not unique. Agreement number 1 (the most common agreement number) is returned every time a "1" is entered in the AgreementID field.

What I want is for my Dlookup to return the first instance in the AgreementName column on the CustomerDatabase Table when the CustomerID is A12345, for example.

Thanks in advance for any help on this one guys, much appreciated.
Sean

Comment: This is my VBA so far:

Comment: 1) Me.CustomerName = DLookup("CustomerName", "CustomerDatabase", "CustomerID = '" & [CustomerID] & "'")

Comment: 2) Me.AgreementName = DLookup("AgreementName", "CustomerDatabase", "AgreementID = '" & [AgreementID] & "'")